# How to have all options in one function?

Tags: c++

So i'm making a text adventure game and I want to be able to have a function which has all the inputs in it. So instead of every time me making an if statement to check for every direction I can just put a function that has all of that in it. How do I make this?

```
    string input;
    while (input != "n", "s", "e", "w")
    { 
        getline(cin, input);
        if (input == "n")
        {
            dTable();
        }
        if (input == "e")
        {
            cout << "You sit on the sofa. Congratulations" << endl;
        }
        if (input == "w")
        {
            cout << "You just ran into a wall" << endl;
        }
        if (input == "s")
        {
            outsideHouse();
        }
        if (input == "stats")
        {
            stats();
        }
        if (input == "help")
        {
            help();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Sorry I am not Siri I don't understand" << endl;
            getline(cin, input);
        }
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: You want to change this loop to function or what? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorta related: I find `std::map` handy here. If you map a `string` to a function that performs the correct behaviour for that string, you can `getline(cin, input); menumap[input]();` some extra wrapping for validation is highly recommended.

Comment: `while (input != "n", "s", "e", "w")` doesn't do what you think it does. You should be using `while (getline(cin, input))` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see different approaches of using functions in here,
thats how I would solve this.
You can focus on adding new questions in the main() part and doesn't have to write
all the if-requests over and over.

```c++
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    void help();
    void stats();

    string check(string input,string n,string s, string w, string e)
    {
    string result;
    if (input == "n"){
        result = n;}

    else if (input == "s"){
        result = s;}

    else if (input == "w"){
        result = w;}

    else if (input == "e"){
        result = e;}

    else if (input == "help"){
        cout << "help" << endl;} //help()

    else if (input == "stats"){
        cout << "stats" << endl;} // stats()

    else if (input == "exit"){
        result = "exit";}

    else
        cout << "Sorry I am not Siri I don't understand. Try again" << endl;


    return result;
    }

    string call()
    {
        string input;
        cout << "Where do you want to go? n s w e" << endl;
        getline(cin, input);
        return input;
    }

    int main()
    {
        bool slope = false;
        string input, result;

        input = call();
        result = check(input,"outside","dTable", "You just ran into a wall", "You sit on the sofa. Congratulations");

        while (slope != true)
        {

            if(result == "house")//room1
          {
            cout << "You are in the house" << endl;
            input = call();
            result = check(input,"outside","dTable", "You just ran into a wall", "You sit on the sofa. Congratulations");
          }
            else if(result == "outside")//room2
          {
            cout << "You are outside"<< endl;
            input = call();
            result = check(input,"You just ran into a wall", "house","dTable", "You sit on the sofa. Congratulations");
          }
            else if(result == "dTable")//room3
          {
            cout << "You are dTable" << endl;
            input = call();
            result = check(input,"You just ran into a wall", "You sit on the sofa. Congratulations","outside","house");
          } ///adding one room after another and connect it with each other
            else if(result == "exit")
          {
              slope = true;
          }
            else
          {
                cout << result << endl;
                input = call();
                //some winning or loosing message here
          }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```