# My if statement prints on every if statement in my while loop regardless if it is false

Tags: c++, if-statement

So i'm making a text adventure game i'm just programming directions. I have a script with north south etc. And then an if statement that says if the user enters something other than a direction it will say that is not a direction and loop to the top but its not working. It will always print That is not a direction even if I enter the right input. Can anyone help?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    string input;
    while (input != "north", "n", "south", "s", "east", "e") {
        cout << "Enter a direction" << endl;
        getline(cin, input);
        if (input == "north" || input == "n") {
            cout << "north" << endl;
        }
        if (input == "west" || input == "w") {
            cout << "west" << endl;
        }
        if (input == "east" || input == "e") {
            cout << "east" << endl;
        }
        if (input == "south" || input == "s") {
            cout << "south" << endl;
        }
        if (input != "n", "s", "e", "w")
        {
            cout << "That is not a direction" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't just make up your own syntax to do things. `input != "north", "n", "south", "s", "east", "e"` and `input != "n", "s", "e", "w"` don't do anything useful.

Comment: In C++, `"north", "n", "south", "s", "east", "e"` will always evaluate to `"e"` and `"n", "s", "e", "w"` will always evaluate to `"w"`

Comment: Why are you capturing the user input after the `while`? Your program never gets the initial condition satisfied

Comment: @Inian, the initial condition will be satisfied because the string is empty and therefore will _not_ match any of the accepted values which is what the initial condition is checking for. A do-while would have been more useful tbh

Comment: Already posted here: https://old.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/e39wv1/if_statement_not_working/

Comment: Also you already asked basically the same thing here: [How to have all options in one function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078988/how-to-have-all-options-in-one-function). Are you even reading the responses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in the comments:

*in C++, `"north", "n", "south", "s", "east", "e"` will always evaluate to `"e"` and `"n", "s", "e", "w"` will always evaluate to `"w"`*

The proper way to do this comparison (for all the possible cases) is:

```
 while (input != "north" && input != "n" && input != "south" && input != "s" && input != "east" && input != "e" && input != "west" && input != "w") {...}
```

For the if it is:

```
if (input != "n" || input != "s" || input != "e" || input != "w") {...}
```

### [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Byd7KmR2S)

Comment: yeah i just tried that and it didn't work it still printed that is not a direction

Comment: @Jacecraft29 You need to change the rest of your if-statements to else if

Comment: @Jacecraft29 actually see my new edit, the while condition was wrong

Comment: ok I did all of the things and now it just says that is not a direction when i enter north and then it ends the program

Comment: @Jacecraft29 please see the demo. I can't guess what your program looks like at this point, but if it doesn't work in the demo, please say here what input is not working

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    string input;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter a direction" << endl;
        getline(cin, input);
        if (input == "north" || input == "n") {
            cout << "north" << endl; break;
        }
        else if (input == "west" || input == "w") {
            cout << "west" << endl; break;
        }
        else if (input == "east" || input == "e") {
            cout << "east" << endl; break;
        }
        else if (input == "south" || input == "s") {
            cout << "south" << endl; break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "That is not a direction" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this also works thanks, my while can be much smaller now

Comment: Why do you have a `break` inside the last `if`? This makes the whole loop redundant as it breaks on 1st iteration anyway.

Comment: Yes. My mistake here.